# How to generate PDF in Django Generic Views?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a template that is rendered by generic List View. I want to give a download link in front of each row of data in table. The download link will create a PDF file of respective rows data. Please tell me how to write a code for that?

Views.py

```
class BookingConfirmationListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = container_booking
    template_name = 'home/booking_confirmation_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_container'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return container_booking.objects.all()
```

Templates look like

```
<table class="table-striped table-hover table-bordered" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Source</th>
    <th>Destination</th>
    <th>Container</th>
    <th>Commodity</th>
    <th>Agreed Rate</th>
    <th>Edit</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
{% for item in all_container %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ item.date }}&nbsp;</td>
    <td>{{ item.place_of_reciept }}&nbsp;</td>
    <td>{{ item.final_place_of_destination }}&nbsp;</td>
    <td>{{ item.equipment_type }}{{ item.quantity }}&nbsp;</td>
    <td>{{ item.commodity }}&nbsp;</td>
    <td>{{ item.agreed_rate }}&nbsp;</td>
    <td><a href="{% url 'home:cont_bk-update' item.id %}" ><i class="fas 
         fa-edit"></i></a></td>
    <td><a href="{% url 'home:cont_bk-delete' item.id %}" ><i class="fas 
         fa-trash"></i></a></td>
    <td>{{ item.approved }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^cont_bkdetail$', views.BookingConfirmationListView.as_view(), 
name='cont_bk-detail'),
url(r'^cont_bk/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', 
views.BookingConfirmationUpdate.as_view(), name='cont_bk-update'),
url(r'^cont_bk/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$', 
views.BookingConfirmationDelete.as_view(), name='cont_bk-delete'),
```

I want that whenever I click download, the PDF file of that row is generated.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not a place where somebody will write code for you. If you show what you have tried so far and what problems appeared then probably somebody will be able to help you.

Comment: I am not telling you to write a code for me, I know the code for generating a PDF file using report-lab. I want to know how to use in this situation  and where to place it in class based views.

Comment: For each of the items in the Listview template you can easily generate a link to a separate view, which will handle pdf creation. In that view you can override get method.

Comment: Can you please show me the snippet of how to do that.